# Static linking with cublas

Tags: cuda, nvcc

I want to link my program with the static version of `cublas`, but I get some undefined references. The command and error are

```
$ nvcc test.cu -o test --cudart=static  -ldl -lpthread -lcurand_static -lcublas_static -lculibos
/home/mahmood/cuda_10.1.168/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcublas_static.a(cublas.o): In function `cublasCtxInit(cublasContext**)':
cublas.compute_75.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x34b): undefined reference to `cublasLtCtxInit'
cublas.compute_75.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x417): undefined reference to `init_gemm_select'
...
...
```

In fact, the library path is fine and the `cublasLtCtxInit` exists in the static library file.

```
$ ls -l /home/mahmood/cuda_10.1.168/lib64/libcublas_static.a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mahmood mahmood 75127082 Jun 27 16:06 /home/mahmood/cuda_10.1.168/lib64/libcublas_static.a
$ grep cublasLtCtxInit ~/cuda_10.1.168/lib64/libcublas_static.a
Binary file /home/mahmood/cuda_10.1.168/lib64/libcublas_static.a matches
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/mahmood/cuda_10.1.168/lib64:
```

So, how can I fix that?

Answer (score 2):

The correct static linking sequence with cublas can be found in the `Makefile` for the `conjugateGradient` [CUDA sample code](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#conjugategradient).

The needed switches for `nvcc` are:

```
-lcublas_static -lcublasLt_static -lculibos
```

example:

```
$ cat t1752.cu
#include <cublas_v2.h>

int main(){

  cublasHandle_t h;
  cublasCreate(&h);
}
$ nvcc t1752.cu -o t1752 -lcublas_static -lcublasLt_static -lculibos
$
```